# JavaFx Webview with Motion

Tags: java, javafx, motion

Is it possible, to view the video which motion streams vie JavaFx Webview and WebEngine?
I have a code which shows me like every website i want, but when i try to open the stream from motion nothing happens

The app code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("WebView.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="WebViewController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="176.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="161.0" layoutY="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../Schreibtisch/test.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: without a minimal code example how you use WebView and which URL you try to access it's hard to help. But the Webkit browser used by the WebEngine is missing quite some features compared to the normal standalone browsers.

Comment: import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("WebView.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();
    }
}

Comment: I formatted and copied the code to your question. Could you please add the fxml and the URL you access?

Comment: sorry fjor the late answer:
url : 127.0.0.1:8081